# select in angularjs not selecting default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is my code extract

```
   <select
        ng-init="joinedStatus=0"
        ng-options="joinstat.name for joinstat in joined track by joinstat.id"
        ng-selected="joinedStatus==joinstat.id"
        ng-model="joinedStatus">
        <option>{{joinedStatus}}</option>
   </select>
```

But still there is no default option selected.

joined is defined as:

`$scope.joined=[{id:0,name:'No'},{id:8,name:'Yes'}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not provide `<option>` inside `select` since `ng-options` will add the options from specified array.

`ng-selected` is of no use. Remove it too.

So, this will work

```
<select ng-init="joinedStatus=joined[0]"
        ng-options="joinstat.name for joinstat in joined track by joinstat.id"
        ng-model="joinedStatus">

</select>
```

Since we have initialized the model with 0th array element. You will see this selected in the select.

Comment: Note that it is not recommended to use "ng-init" in such cases. It would be better to initialize "joinedStatus" in you controller.